# Create a div from Javascript function (innerHTML)

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I want to call a function which creates divs headings and paragraphs inside my HTML code, I can't make the HTML appear though

Here is my JS function:

```
const about = () => {
    document.getElementById('about').innerHTML = '<div class="about"><h1>About</h1><div><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p></div></div>';
}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
<div class = "about-content" id = 'about'>

</div>
```

and it doesn't seem to be working.. do I need to call the function somewhere in my code?

Comment: Don't use the same name for a global function as the ID of an element. IDs automatically become global variables, and the names will conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to call the function,

You can do this when the page loads like so..

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    about();
}, false);
```

or you could use a setTimeout

```
window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(() => {
       about();
   }, 1000);
}
```

or you could have it on a click event

**html**

```
<button id="about-select"></button>
```

**javascript**

```
const button = document.querySelector('#about-select');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   about();
});
```

or you could just do this

```
<button onclick="about()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thankyou, I can get it to appear upon page load. Now I need to figure out how to call it only when a certain button is clicked. thanks

Comment: Yeah so if you look at my last example, you can use an eventListener so when you click a button it will call the function I will write a full example

Comment: That does work. However I have been advised that I could find a solution without making any changes to my .js file

Comment: @AlexTurner please see my latest edit, this should answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Inside your script add something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    about();
}
```

That will call your function when the page has loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to call the function.

Your function is ready to use but not called yet.

So, inside your JavaScript script use `about();` to call your function.